# Java StreamAPI: not sorting Map by its Instant-Keys

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

im trying to group a list of Instant-Timestamps and sort them due to their natural ordering.

```
@Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {

        List<Instant> asList = Arrays.asList(createInstants());

        Map<Instant, List<Instant>> collect = asList.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.groupingBy((Instant instant) -> instant));

        System.out.println(collect);

    }

public Instant[] createInstants() {
    Instant instant1 = Instant.from(ZonedDateTime.of(2016, 12, 25, 12, 25, 30, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault()));
    Instant instant2 = Instant.from(ZonedDateTime.of(2013, 8, 11, 13, 33, 45, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault()));
    Instant instant3 = Instant.from(ZonedDateTime.of(2010, 3, 15, 13, 33, 45, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault()));

    return new Instant[] { instant1, instant2, instant3 };
}
```

But it doesnt seem to work. Instead of :

```
{2016-12-25T11:25:30Z=[2016-12-25T11:25:30Z], 2013-08-11T11:33:45Z=[2013-08-11T11:33:45Z],2010-03-15T12:33:45Z=[2010-03-15T12:33:45Z]}
```

im getting this:

```
{2016-12-25T11:25:30Z=[2016-12-25T11:25:30Z], 2010-03-15T12:33:45Z=[2010-03-15T12:33:45Z], 2013-08-11T11:33:45Z=[2013-08-11T11:33:45Z]}
```

In other words: the result is not sorted. Why?

Comment: What guarantees does `Collectors.groupingBy` make about the sorted-ness of its resulting `Map`?

Comment: You don't need a `List` to stream; just use `Arrays.stream(createInstants())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Collectors.groupingBy()` overload you're using doesn't return an ordered map. If you want your result to be ordered, you can specify `LinkedHashMap` with [another overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
Collectors.groupingBy((Instant instant) -> instant), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 2):

`Collectors.groupingBy` makes no ordering guarantees - in practice, it returns a `HashMap`.

(And also, it's not clear why you want a map here instead of a set?)

Probably the simplest solution is to write

```
collect(toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>()));
```

...which collects into a sorted set.

Comment: Isn't `TreeSet::new` nicer?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I assumed when I started writing that we'd need a comparator.